# Get Parameter from axml to Command

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

The AXML:

```
<Button  
android:id="@+id/greenButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Green"
local:MvxBind="Click ShowColorCommand, CommandParameter='Green'"/>
```

and the ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    public ICommand ShowColorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<ColorViewModel>(new { color = ??? } ));
        }
    }
}
```

How do I read/use the CommandParameter from the .axml ('Green') in my Command? What do I need to put inside the "???"

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the generic `MvxCommand<T>` form - there's a string example in [Using MvxCommand With CommandParameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234539/using-mvxcommand-with-commandparameter-binding)

```
new MvxCommand<string>(param =>
  {
      if (param == "foo")               
      {
        // do something
      }
      else if (param == "bar")
      {
        // do something else
      }
  });
```