# How to bind button to Cmd with parameter in Android + MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a very simple application that rely on MVVMCross + Xamarin Android.

I have been able to create a WP8 application LoginView (Username + Password + Submit Button) that bind to a Cmd with parameter(which will be my password) in the ViewModel . Now I try to do the same with Android . How to express the CommandParameter(which is another field of the view) in the axml file for my LoginView?

```
    public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly ILoginService _loginService;

    public LoginViewModel(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    private string _username;
    public string Username
    { 
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username); }
    }

    private string _error;
    public string Error {
        get { return _error; }
        set { _error = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Error); }
    }

    #region LoginCmd
    private MvxCommand<string> _loginCmd;
    public ICommand LoginCmd
    {
        get
        {
            _loginCmd = _loginCmd ?? new MvxCommand<string>(DoLoginCmd);
            return _loginCmd;
        }
    }

    private void DoLoginCmd(string password)
    {
        try
        {
            _loginService.Login(Username, password);
            ShowViewModel<ProjectsListViewModel>();
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            Error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For general commandparameter binding see [Using MvxCommand With CommandParameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234539/using-mvxcommand-with-commandparameter-binding)

For binding to a value within the View, my general answer is **don't**

MvvmCross doesn't support ElementName or RelativeSource type binding source.

Instead all bindings are to the ViewModel/DataContext

For your app example, you could easily bind the Password to a property in your ViewModel - just like you do with UserName

---

**Update** after comments discussion.

If `Password` is a special case because of Xaml security concerns, then some options you could try are:

- you could work around those security concerns using AttachedProperties - see links like http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html for details
- you could bind the `Password` property on Android and iOS and then use the Tibet binding  syntax to bind the Click event with a ViewModel bound CommandParameter - something like `Click CommandParameter(LoginCmd, Password)`
- you could use ViewModel based-logic to use either the parameter-passed-in Password or (when null) the ViewModel Password property (`password = password ?? Password;`)
- you could use code-behind or custom control binding tricks to make the command parameter work... e.g. you could:

  - inherit a LoginButton from Button
  - add a `SetPasswordEditText(EditText text)` method to LoginButton
  - add a `PasswordClick` ICommand property to LoginButton and cause it to fire
  - use a little code-behind to wire up the UI to provide the Password at Command-time
  - this might look like

.

```
 public class LoginButton : Button
 {
    public LoginButton(Context c, IAttributeSet a) : base(c,a) {
       this.Click += (s,e) => {
         if (LoginClick == null) return;
         if (PasswordEditText == null) return;
         if (LoginClick.CanExecute(PasswordEditText.Text))
           LoginClick.Execute(PasswordEditText.Text);
       }
    }

    public ICommand LoginClick {get;set;}
    public EditText PasswordEditText {get;set;}
 }

 // codebehind in OnCreate as:
 var l = FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.the_login_button);
 var p = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.the_password_box);

 l.PasswordEditText = p;

 // Axml is:
 <LoginButton 
    local:MvxBind="LoginClick LoginCmd"
    android:... etc />
```

Comment: Hi Stuart. I was initially binding the PasswordBox to a property as you were suggesting, but found that PasswordBox on WP8 doesn't allow binding the Password property. What would be you suggestion to be cross plateform? Would you recommend this solution http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html?

Comment: Yes, on WinPhone (which is already locked down for security) I'd be happy to use that sort of attached binding proper approach. For Android and iOS if you really want to keep the same `MvxCommand<string>` format for your Login command, then the Tibet binding style should probably save us - you can probably bind the Password to a `Password` ViewModel property on Android and iOS and can then use a binding  for the command like `Click CommandParameter(LoginCommand, Password)` - I think that sort of thing should work... Alternatively, you could also (snip - let me edit the answer)

Comment: Thanks very much will consider the different options.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on the solution 2 (CommandParameter with Tibet binding). What do I need to add the view the model to make it work ?